# Strange way object is being moved by armature

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, error

I parented objects to my armature and applied weight painting. I started off on a different part of the model, where the weight painting wasn't the entire object.

I thought that was the problem, but with the example I have (in the video below) it is with a singular object that is 100% red in weight paint. Upon rotating the bone it is weighted to in pose mode, the object does not rotate all the way with the bone. And when the bone reached 180 degrees, the object flips for some reason.

[image: Animation of bone reaching 180 degrees and the object flipping]

Comment: Try to switch [Rotation mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/appendices/rotations.html) ... Or try to rotate on a X axis (R, X) ...does it make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Your foot is probably assigned to some other vertex groups, when it should not, it makes it controlled by some other bones, so select the foot only and in the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups > Remove from All Groups*:

[image]

Then keep the foot selected, select the foot vertex group (the vertex group that has the name of the bone that is supposed to control it) and click on *Assign*:

[image]